# How to deploy NestJS microservice to AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, microservices

I want to deploy my api-gateway and a microservice to AWS Elastic Beanstalk but couldn't handle it.

I am using network load balancer that accept tcp connections from port 5000 but my api-gateway still can't connect to microservice. There is no error in console by the way. It is just returning timeout.

`main.ts` - microservice

```js
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config'
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core'
import { MicroserviceOptions, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices'
import { FastifyAdapter, NestFastifyApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-fastify'

import { AppModule } from './app.module'
import { AllExceptionsFilter } from './filters/rpc-exception.filter'

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter({ logger: true })
  )

  app.enableCors()

  const config = app.get<ConfigService>(ConfigService)

  app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({ transport: Transport.TCP, options: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: +config.get('TCP_PORT', 5000) || 5000
  } })

  app.useGlobalFilters(new AllExceptionsFilter())

  await app.startAllMicroservices()
  await app.listen(config.get('PORT', 3000) || 3000, '0.0.0.0')
}

bootstrap()
```

`Dockerfile` - microservice

```
...

###################
# PRODUCTION
###################
FROM node:18-alpine As production

ARG NODE_ENV=production

ARG MONGODB_URI=
ARG MONGODBADMIN_URI=

ARG PORT=8080
ARG TCP_PORT=5000

ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
ENV MONGODB_URI=${MONGODB_URI}
ENV MONGODBADMIN_URI=${MONGODBADMIN_URI}
ENV PORT=${PORT}
ENV TCP_PORT=${TCP_PORT}

COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

EXPOSE 8080 5000

ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "dist/main" ]
```

`mymodule.module.ts` - api-gateway

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config'
import { ClientsModule, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices'

import { MyModuleController } from './mymodule.controller'
import { MyModuleService } from './mymodule.service'

@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.registerAsync([
      {
        name: 'MY_SERVICE',
        useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
          transport: Transport.TCP,
          options: {
            host: configService.get('MY_SERVICE_HOST'),
            port: configService.get('MY_SERVICE_PORT')
          }
        }),
        inject: [ConfigService]
      }
    ])
  ],
  controllers: [MyModuleController],
  providers: [MyModuleService]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

`Dockerfile` - api-gateway

```
...

###################
# PRODUCTION
###################
FROM node:18-alpine As production

ARG NODE_ENV=production

ARG MY_SERVICE_HOST=my-service.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
ARG MY_SERVICE_PORT=5000

ARG PORT=8080

ARG JWT_SECRET=

ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
ENV MY_SERVICE_HOST=${MY_SERVICE_HOST}
ENV MY_SERVICE_PORT=${MY_SERVICE_PORT}
ENV PORT=${PORT}
ENV JWT_SECRET=${JWT_SECRET}

COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "dist/main" ]
```

`network load balancer` - microservice

[image]

This works perfectly in local but api gateway can't connect to microservice it is just returning 504 Gateway Time-out after 1 minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you need to create a `Dockerrun.aws.json` file

```json
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "8080"
    },
    {
      "ContainerPort": "5000",
      "HostPort": "5000"
    }
  ]
}
```